# Paste from current sheet to end of book into Word docs as picture

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I currently have a working macro (modified code from [TheSpreadsheetGuru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba)) that copies from A1 to last used row in column H and pastes that data as a picture to a Microsoft Word document. It works great, but I have to run the macro more than 20 times (once for each sheet), and I have multiple reports I run each week with this same criteria. Is it possible to have this code iterate through all the worksheets from the active sheet (which would be the first sheet needed) through the end of the workbook? I could use the worksheet names (Linda is first, Victoria is last sheet) but the names change fairly often and more sheets are often added, and I don't want to have to change the code each time.

```
    Sub PasteAsPicture()

    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim startcell As Range

    Set startcell = Range("H4")
    PicNme = ActiveSheet.name & ".docx"

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Copy Range from Excel
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, startcell.Row).End(xlUp).Row
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H" & lastrow)
    End With

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If

  On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    'WordApp.Visible = True
    'WordApp.Activate

    'Create a New Document
    Set myDoc = WordApp.documents.Add

    'Copy Excel Table Range
    tbl.CopyPicture xlPrinter

    'Paste Table into MS Word
    With myDoc.PageSetup
        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .TopMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(1)
        .LeftMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With

    With myDoc
        .Paragraphs(1).Range.Paste
        .SaveAs Filename:="H:\QBIRT Reports\New Establishments\Reports\" & PicNme
        .Close
    End With

EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a plethora of articles/threads/blogs that show how to loop through worksheets with VBA.  It's pretty easy, and you don't need to even know the worksheet names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx) uses the [For Each... Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596.aspx) to loop over arrays and collections.  Using this method you can repeat the same action on every worksheet in the workbook.

```
' Calls PasteAsPicture, for each sheet in the workbook.
Sub ForEachWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Loop over every sheet in the book.
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        ' Paste as picture requires the current sheet to be selected.
        ' You cannot activate hidden and very hidden sheets, without first unhiding.
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then


            ws.Activate
            PasteAsPicture
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to start building up a library of VBA macros, that you can call from any workbook, research Excel's start up path and .xla file format.